# How to use stuff() for listing user roles per application?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table `users`

```
application  user_id    user_role     role_permissions
-------------------------------------------------------
1            20          A             add
1            20          B             edit
1            30          A             add
1            20          B             edit
1            30          V             delete
1            20          G             duplicate
1            40          X             purge
2            20          W             hide
2            20          P             unhide
2            40          X             purge
```

I want to list all the roles that each user has **per application**, as follows:

```
application  user_id    roles       permissions
-----------------------------------------------
1            20         A;B;G       add;edit;duplicate
1            30         A;V         add;delete
1            40         X           purge
2            20         W;P         hide;unhide
2            40         X           purge
```

I have been trying this using `stuff` but I am unsuccessful:

```
select users.user_id,
       stuff
       ((
           select ';' + user_role from users a
           where  a.user_id = b.user_id
           for xml path('')),1,1,'' 
       ) as roles
 from users b
```

This gives me:

```
user_id  permissions
-----------------------
20       A;B;B;G
20       A;B;B;G
20       A;B;B;G
30       A;V
30       A;V
...
etc
```

**How can I get the distinct rows PER application?**

Comment: As was pointed out to me, by another, `STUFF()` is not what actually places the values from the different rows into one column, `STUFF()` handles the concatenation, while `FOR XML Path` does all the transfering of data.

Comment: Looks to me like it is working just fine. For each row in users you are getting their permissions. Perhaps you want only the distinct rows?

Comment: @RyanWilson Actually, stuff does not concatenate anything. We use `Stuff` to remove the first `;` char.

Comment: @ZoharPeled "The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position." Sure sounds like some concatenation to me. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Just as a side note, starting at 2017 version, SQL Server supports [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @RyanWilson Well, Take a look at [this online demo.](http://rextester.com/ZRJUX94627) `Stuff` works somewhat like `replace`, only instead of taking a substring to replace it takes an index and a length. (When length is 0, it does not replace any part of the original string, just inserts the new substring into the original string)

Comment: @Pr0no Why do you have duplicate records in the table to begin with?

Comment: Please note that I have added the complication of grouping per application. I forgot to include this in the original post!

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is not my table. It is from a legacy system and I cannot change it. In reality, the table is much bigger but I hope that I'm distilling from it what is relevant for this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct` *before* the outer select:

```
select u.user_id,
       stuff( (select distinct';' + user_role
               from users u2
               where u.user_id = u2.user_id and u.application = u2.application
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, '' 
            ) as roles
from (select distinct user_id, application from users u) u;
```

I don't know what `obj_id` is.  The obvious correlation condition uses `user_id`.

Comment: My bad, changed it :) Please note that I now have added the complication of needing the roles per application (forgot to mention this originally). Please help me understand how this works out in your suggestion?

Comment: Basically, you need to add the application id to the select distinct query, and also to the condition on the where clause of the subquery - ` and u.application_id = u2.application_id`

Comment: @Pr0no . . . That is a pretty minor change to the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want four columns in your results, I think you need something like this:

```
select
    u.application,
    u.user_id,
    stuff( (select distinct';' + user_role
           from users u2
           where  u.user_id = u2.user_id
           and u.application = u3.application
           for xml path('')
          ), 1, 1, '' 
        ) as roles
    stuff( (select distinct';' + role_permissions
           from users u3
           where  u.user_id = u3.user_id
           and u.application = u3.application
           for xml path('')
          ), 1, 1, '' 
        ) as permissions
from (select distinct application, user_id from users u) u;
```

Comment: Please note that I have added the complication of permissions per application. How does that change your suggestion?

Comment: Updated it to include application as well.